# Process large gzipped JSON Lines file in R

Tags: r

There is this large gzipped JSON Lines file I would like first to transform to CSV and then import into a duckdb database.

Unfortunately, the files is too large for my memory. So I would like to process it chunkwise.

I tried the `LaF` package but it seems it does not work with gzipped files.

What would a minimal example look like?

EDIT:

More specifically, I‘d like to parse this file (500MB) for example:
https://openalex.s3.amazonaws.com/data/authors/updated_date%3D2023-07-21/part_000.gz

And create three csv out of it, i.e. flatten the JSON in a similar way as in [this python script](https://github.com/ourresearch/openalex-documentation-scripts/blob/main/flatten-openalex-jsonl.py#L214).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DuckDB can import data directly from newline-delimited JSON files, it can also handle compression.

If there's a reason not to do that from command line, the process can be executed through R / DBI as well, here with a tiny toy reprex:

```r
library("DBI")

# prepare reprex, store a compressed ndjson as sample_nd.json.gz
ndjson <-'{"key1":"value1", "key2": "value1"}
{"key1":"value2", "key2": "value2"}
{"key1":"value3", "key2": "value3"}
'
ndjson_gz <- gzfile("sample_nd.json.gz", "w")
write(ndjson, ndjson_gz)
close(ndjson_gz)

con <- dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir = "sample.duckdb")

# load compressed ndjson to a 'sample' table, 
# compression type is guessed from file name (.json.gz)
dbExecute(con, "INSTALL json; LOAD json;")
#> [1] 0
dbExecute(con, "CREATE TABLE sample AS SELECT * 
                FROM read_json('sample_nd.json.gz', 
                                format = 'newline_delimited', 
                                columns = {key1: 'VARCHAR', key2: 'VARCHAR'})")
#> [1] 3

# list / describe / select first records
dbListTables(con)
#> [1] "sample"
dbGetQuery(con, "DESCRIBE sample")
#>   column_name column_type null  key default extra
#> 1        key1     VARCHAR  YES <NA>    <NA>    NA
#> 2        key2     VARCHAR  YES <NA>    <NA>    NA
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM sample LIMIT 3")
#>     key1   key2
#> 1 value1 value1
#> 2 value2 value2
#> 3 value3 value3
dbDisconnect(con)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

For reference,
JSON Import guide: https://duckdb.org/docs/guides/import/json_import
JSON Loading (read_json & read_json_auto documentation and more examples): https://duckdb.org/docs/data/json/overview

If there's a *really* good reason to pre-process that dataset in R first, you can look into streamed JSON processing with a custom handler, `jsonlite::stream_in()` / `jsonlite::stream_out()`